# Can one program an STM32H7 chip directly using an ST link/V2

Tags: stm32, st-link

I recently bought an STM32H7 chip, soldered onto a breakout board. I have been trying to program it using the ST-link/V2 using system workbench for STM32. I get the error: "Wrong device detected". The datasheets do not give me much information.

My question is: Is it possible to program the STM32H7 microcontroller directly, using the ST-link/V2?

Comment: What version of System Workbench are you using? The STM32H7 is a newer part, and might not be recognized by older software.

Comment: @duskwuff Indeed I had to update my System workbench so that was part of the solution. I will post my entire fix below

Comment: @LongPham I am infact using STM32CubeMX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All STM32 and STM8 chips can be debugged and programmed by an ST Link V2.
However, you might need to update the ST Link firmware.

See if it works with the ST Link Utility: [STSW-LINK004](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link004.html).

If yours does not work, then your breakout board will be faulty.

Answer (score 1):

As this post may suggest, I am a bit of a newbie. Nonetheless, I managed to correct my mistake.

It turns out my problem was based mainly on my connection between the ST link and the STM32H7 chip, as well as the way I generated my code in STM32CubeMX.

These are the steps I followed to make it work

**Software side**

- Created a project in STM32CubeMX for my chip.
- Set the required pin setup, and chose **SERIAL WIRE** as my debug option(Sys)
- Generated the code for system workbench
- I set the debug mode to SWD in System workbench under Run configuration

**Hardware side**

- The datasheet does not mention this, but the SWCLK pin has to be **pulled down** to VSS, and the SWDIO pin has to be **pulled up** to VDD.
- Make sure Pin 19(If using the 20 pin ST link V2) is connected to the VDD of the MCU, together with Pins 1 and 2.

Comment: Both SWCLK and SWDIO do not require any pull resistors.